ASUS Vivobook laptop keyboard not working Ubuntu 24
model X1504VAP, I tried posted remedies, cant patch kernel (My first attempt  at this, with modified patch file .ident = "Asus Vivobook X1504VAP",), upgraded to kernel 6.11rc, tried changing grub entries, X11 conf entries, none seem to work for this Vivobook model purchased July 2024 does anyone have the same issue or know of any working fixes?
It seems I have trouble patching kernel after all, trying a downloaded patch file for another ASUS model, the command
"patch -p1 <  fix-irq-vivobook.patch" returns messages:
Hunk #1 succeeded at 792 with fuzz 2
Hunk #2 FAILED at 429
looks like patch file only valid for an older kernel version. Anyone aware of a patch for 6.11?

possibly related (will it be fixed in Ubuntu 24.04.1?) Debian User Forums. Seems to be a known issue in Ubuntu too.
